# Is $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\varphi(k)}{k}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, totient-function

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be defined as $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\varphi(k)}{k}$ where $\varphi$ is the euler totient function. Is $(a_n)$ convergent. If so, what is its limit?

I have checked it numerically; it seems to converge to the value
$$
a\approx 0.6079384135652464404586775568799731914204890312331725
$$
However, I cannot think of a way to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Other_formulae_involving_.CF.86) you can find that the value you're looking for is $ \frac{6}{\pi^2} $

Answer (score 2):

Start from $$\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) = n$$

which yields $$L_1(s) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s}
= \frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}
\quad\text{and}\quad
L_2(s) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\varphi(n)/n}{n^s}
= \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+1)}.$$

We have at $s=1$ being a simple pole
$$\mathrm{Res}(L_2(s); s=1) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

and therefore by the 
[Wiener-Ikehara theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Ikehara_theorem)
we obtain $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\varphi(k)}{k}
\sim \frac{1}{n} \frac{6}{\pi^2} n
= \frac{6}{\pi^2}.$$

**Remark.** This is a powerful theorem and hence we may or may not be permitted to apply it to this problem.

Comment: in my opinion that the value is the residue at the pole is more the theorem of fourier/laplace inversion than  Wiener-Ikehara's lemma which is quite simple to prove

Answer (score 0):

See a result from [this paper](https://zbmath.org/?format=complete&q=an:0146.06003) or the sum in [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function#Other_formulae_involving_.CF.86).  The sum may be approximated:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\varphi(k)}{k} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}n + \mathcal{O}\left((\log n)^{2/3}(\log \log n)^{4/3}\right)$$

Since, as $n\to \infty$, $n>(\log n)^{2/3}(\log \log n)^{4/3}$, the big-O term drops out.  Thus, we're left with the limit being $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.